# El Expressions no longer working

Tags: html, jsp, el

I'm working on something for class, and I was just playing around with scroll-bars for my table.  All the sudden my EL expressions stopped working. I did not touch my controller classes at all. I have tested the methods in my models and controller. Everything seems to be in working order. Which means its a tag somewhere or something like that. However I've been all over this and cannot find it. I am super new with EL expressions so its possible I'm missing something obvious. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<%-- 
Document   : Index
Created on : Feb 8, 2016, 12:43:30 PM
Author     : andre_000
--%>

<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Book Inventory</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Author Inventory</a>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-menu">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse-menu">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h1>Author Inventory</h1>

                <table class="table table-hover active">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Author Name</th>
                            <th>Date Added</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>


                    <tbody>

                        <c:forEach var="author" items="${authorList}">
                            <tr>
                                <td id=${author.authorId}>
                                    <c:out value="${author.authorId}" />
                                </td>
                                <td class="authorname" id="<c:out value="${author.authorName}"/>" >
                                    <c:out value="${author.authorName}"/>
                                </td>
                                <td id=${author.dateAdded}>

                                    <c:out value="${author.dateAdded}"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>  
                    </tbody>

                </table>
                <h1>${errorMsg}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="add" class="col-md-8">


                        <form method="POST" action="AuthorController">
                            <h2 class="toolbar" >Add a new Author</h2>
                            <label>Enter Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" value=""/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add" />
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="add" />
                        </form>

                    </div>
                    <div id="editDelete" class="col-md-8">

                        <form method="POST" action="AreaCalculator" name="Triangle" id="triangle" class="calcBox">
                            <h2>Edit or Delete?</h2>
                            <label>Name:</label>
                            <input id="name" type="text" name="height" value=""/>
                            <br>
                            <label>Date Added:</label>
                            <input id="date" type="text" name="base" value=""/>
                            <br>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="shapeID" value="TRIANGLE" />
                        </form>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <form method="POST" action="AreaCalculator" name="Circle" id="circle" class="calcBox">
                            <h2>Circle Calculator</h2>
                            <label>Enter Radius</label>
                            <input type="text" name="radius" value=""/>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="shapeID" value="CIRCLE" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="navbar-text"><i>&copy; 2016 Andrew Wintermyer</i></p>  
        </div>

    </nav>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var name;
            $('#editDelete').hide();

             $('.authorname').click(function () {
                    name = $(this).attr('id'); 
                });

            $('.table > tbody > tr').click(function () {


                $('#editDelete').show();
                $('#add').hide();
                $('#name').val(name);
                $('#date').val("Today");
            });
        });

    </script>


</body>
```

I even reverted my project to an earlier working github commit and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is, I was not protecting my addrecord method from adding null records to my table.  Once in there they really messed up my getallrecords method. I really wasted an hour there.  The lesson to be learned is validate all parameters even if you're just hacking around.